# Что такое Context?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, context

Кто-нибудь объясните по-человечески что такое `Context` в Android. Имею опыт использования, но чувствую неудовлетворенность, так как четкий его смысл ускользает.

UPD. Хотелось бы узнать, исходя из вашей практики, как он меняется или не меняется в ходе работы приложения,
 меняется ли он от активности к активности, от активности к сервису...или он разный у каждого компонента приложения, имеет разные возможности в разных ситуациях...

Comment: Хорошая статья о контексте. Подходит под UPD вопроса.
https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Context** - *интерфейс предоставляющий глобальную информацию о среде приложения. Является абстрактным классом, реализация которого происходит с помощью Android системы. Context позволяет получить доступ к ресурсам приложения и его классам, а также осуществлять вызовы операций на уровне приложения, к примеру: Запуск Activity,  Service, Broadcasting and Receiving intents, и тд.*

*Источник*  [Context](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/Context.html)

Диаграмма:

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Хороший вопрос. Частенько его задают на собеседованиях на позицию Android девелопера. Наиболее краткий и верный ответ на этот вопрос может звучать примерно так:

> **Context** - это интерфейс доступа к функциям операционной системы
>   Android.

Ну и, конечно же, это не является каким-то секретом, все **[доступно](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/Context.html)**.

Comment: Понятное дело, что доступ я тоже имею. Но мне хочется как-то по-русски, по-дружески неформально - из опыта. Например, меняется ли он от активности к активности, от активности к сервису, в ходе работы приложения...или он разный у каждого компонента приложения, имеет разные возможности в разных ситуациях...

Comment: Я так понимаю, у вас Context ассоциируется в подобием Handle(HWND, идентификатор объекта) в среде Windows?
На более низком уровне(там, где си-код) так и есть. Именно поэтому у каждой ui-сущности есть контекст, который используется более "низкоуровнево" при передаче в методы, предоставляемые SDK. Посмотрите, как интерпретируется Context в native коде.