# Как получить текст из ресурсов (string.xml)

Tags: android, resources

У меня есть некий код (Android 2.3.3).

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(R.string.regexDate + R.string.regexTime + R.string.regexLast);
```

Метод `Pattern.compile(String string)`, требует параметр в виде строк, но из  `string.xml` я получаю `int`. Т.е. я получаю итендификаторы из `R.java`, но мне нужны сразу строки...

Cами ресурсы из string.xml

```
<string name="regexDate" >^[2][\\d]{3}[0-1]{1}[\\d]{1}[0-3]{1}[\\d][_]</string>
<string name="regexTime">[0-2][\\d]([0-5][\\d]){2}[_]</string>
<string name="regexLast">[0]{3}[b][\\.][d][b]$</string>
```

Читаем документацию...

Один вариант приведения в качестве строки:

```
String s = getString(R.string.regexDate);
```

Второй вариант:

```
Resources res = getResources();
res.getString(R.string.regexDate)
```

Не могу использовать данные варианты, т.к. методов `getString(...), getResources()` Eclipse не видит.

Как мне брать из `string.xml` сразу строку, а не ее `id`? Если можно с примером.

Answer (score 2):

Методы `getResources()` или `getString()` вызываются из `Context`, так как `context` имеет доступ к ресурсам программы.

А строку получить нельзя из `string.xml`.

Как вариант костыля, можно написать `enum`:), но так не стоит делать либо используй `public static final string` в классе в котором пользуешься Pattern

Comment: Дополню комментарием о том, что в `Java` метод не может сам по себе существовать. Он принадлежит какому-либо классу. Если вы вызываете метод без четкого указания объекта, у которого вы его хотите вызвать, это расценивается, как попытка вызвать метод у объекта, внутри которого вы работаете. То есть `getString()` на самом деле интерпритируется, как `this.getString()`. А теперь посмотрите, есть ли у вашего класса, внутри которого вы работаете метод `getString()`

Comment: @metalurgus Наличие метода у самого класса и классов, от которых он наследуется, если совсем точно.

Answer (score 2):

Используемые вами методы `getResources()` и `getString()` - методы [контекста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/506401/177345) (класса `Context`) и чтобы получить результат, вам нужно сначала получить в свой класс контекст любым [доступным способом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526091/177345), от передачи в свой класс через конструктор оттуда, где контекст есть (например, при вызове своего класса из активити, которая наследуется от класса `Context` и содержит его) до получения контекста из `Application` - этот класс доступен всегда в приложении и содержит контекст.

Получив экземпляр контекста вы можете использовать его методы в своем классе:

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
res.getString(R.string.regexDate);
```

Напрямую контекст можно получить из классов `Application`, `Activity` (и ее наследников), `Service`, `Fragment` (и его наследников, через метод `getActivity()`) и др. Всего [45 классов](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html?hl=ru) (раздел *Known Indirect Subclasses*)